# Swift optional values during initialization preventing default initializer inheritance

Tags: swift, initialization, constants, option-type, swift-playground

In Swift:

1) If you provide a default value for all of the stored properties in a class, then you inherit the default initializer, ie - `init()`.

-- AND --

2) A property of any optional type defaults to the value of nil, ie - `var shouldBeNill: String? //should initially be nill`

-- THEREFORE --

I would expect this code to work:

```
class Product {
    let name: String?
}

let product = Product()
```

But when I type it in as a playground, I get the error: "class Product has no initializers".

Why isn't Product inheriting the default initializer `init()`? I know I can make this work by explicitly setting `let name: String? = nil`, but I'm unsure why I have to do this. Is this an error on Swift's side, or is there something I am not quite grasping?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are on the right track. The issue here is actually the `let` vs `var`.

`let` declares the property constant. In this case `Product` would have an optional constant `name` of type `String` with no initial value, and this of course makes no sense.

The compiler complains about a lacking `init()` function because `let` properties are allowed to be set once during init(), as part of object construction, if not defined already in declaration eg.

```
let name: String = "Im set!" // OK
let name: String? = nil // OK, but very weird :) 
let name = "Im set!" // OK, type not needed, implicit.
let name: String // OK, but needs to be set to a string during init()
let name: String? // OK, but needs to be set to string or nil during init()

let name // Not OK
```

[The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) - Constants and Variables

Comment: Good question and very exhaustive answer.